# Launch and write to terminal in Qt

Tags: qt, popen, ping, qprocess

I am coding in linux using Qt. I understand that with popen or QProcess I can launch terminal from my program, but how do I write into to it? I google around people are suggesting fork() and pipe(). 
My purpose is to do an ICMP ping with the terminal, and stop when ping successfully. I made it with popen, but I couldn't stop the ping process thus my program won't run.

Answer (score 1):

You don't write anything to terminal because there's no terminal. You pass name of a program to run and its arguments as arguments of the [`QProcess::start`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#start) method. If you only need to know if ping was successful or not it's enough to check the exit code of the process which you started earlier using `QProcess::start`; you don't have to read its output.

from [ping(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)

> If ping does not receive any reply
>   packets at all it will exit with code
>   1. If a packet count and deadline are both specified, and fewer than count
>   packets are received by the time the
>   deadline has arrived, it will also
>   exit with code 1. On other error it
>   exits with code 2. Otherwise it exits
>   with code 0. This makes it possible to
>   use the exit code to see if a host is
>   alive or not.

By default `ping` under Linux runs until you stop it. You can however use `-c X` option to send only X packets and `-w X` option to set timeout of the whole process to X seconds. This way you can limit the time ping will take to run.
Below is a working example of using `QProcess` to run ping program on Windows. For Linux you have to change ping options accordingly (for example `-n` to `-c`). In the example, ping is run up to X times, where X is the option you give to `Ping` class constructor. As soon as any of these executions returns with exit code 0 (meaning success) the `result` signal is emitted with value true. If no execution is successful the `result` signal is emitted with value false.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>


class Ping : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Ping(int count)
    : QObject(), count_(count) {

        arguments_ << "-n" << "1" << "example.com";

        QObject::connect(&process_,
                         SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)),
                         this,
                         SLOT(handlePingOutput(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)));
    };

public slots:

    void handlePingOutput(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus) {
        qDebug() << exitCode;
        qDebug() << exitStatus;
        qDebug() << static_cast<QIODevice*>(QObject::sender())->readAll();
        if (!exitCode) {
            emit result(true);
        } else {
            if (--count_) {
                QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(ping()));
            } else {
                emit result(false);
            }
        }
    }

    void ping() {
        process_.start("ping", arguments_);
    }

signals:

    void result(bool res);

private:

    QProcess process_;
    QStringList arguments_;
    int count_;
};


class Test : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Test() : QObject() {};

public slots:
    void handle(bool result) {
        if (result)
            qDebug() << "Ping suceeded";
        else
            qDebug() << "Ping failed";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    Test test;
    Ping ping(3);
    QObject::connect(&ping,
                     SIGNAL(result(bool)),
                     &test,
                     SLOT(handle(bool)));

    ping.ping();
    app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful! But I don't understand, don't we have to pass the program path or something to QProcess::start ? You are passing the string "ping", how does that works?

Comment: You are right, we have to pass program path as an argument to `QProcess::start`. In the example it's just `ping` because that's enough if the ping program is located in one of directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. However if it's not or you don't want to count on the `PATH` variable you have to give the full path. By the way; you might want to accept my answer as the solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes I'm using the answer that you provided, I tried to ping google and it returned:
("-c", "5", "209.85.175.147") 
QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
0 
1 
"PING 209.85.175.147 (209.85.175.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 209.85.175.147: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=21.5 ms
" 
Ping succeeded 

But when I tried to ping something that's not connected, it returned:
("-c", "5", "192.168.1.100") 
QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
0 
1 
"" 
Ping succeeded 

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Sorry for the messy codes. I'm saying that when I ping both connected and unconnected source, the exit code returned is 0 and QProcess status is 1, and both said "ping succeeded".